# Contacts lost after deleting MS account from phone

Tags: contacts, microsoft-account, outlook

Recently I deleted my Outlook account on my Nokia Lumia 730 and lost all the contacts which were stored in the mobile. How do I retrieve them. It seems the contacts are stored in outlook.com. Can anyone help?

Comment: Yes, the contacts should be stored at outlook.com. Have you tried logging in with your Outlook/MS account?

Comment: But I lost the password and doesn't the contacts are supposed to be in the mobile sim..

Comment: You can reset your password at https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx

Answer (score 1):

By default, Windows Phone stores you contacts within an online service (be it Outlook.com, Gmail, etc.). You will need to add the account back, to get the contacts - if required, you can [reset your account password online](https://account.live.com/ResetPassword.aspx)